# jQuery - find last occurrence of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 divs, with the same id, pagination, one is at the top of the page, the other at the bottom.

What I'd like to do, is find the last id, so this would be the `<div id="pagination"></div>` at the bottom of the page and add some more HTML, so it looks like:

```
<div id="pagination"></div><hr />
```

Is this possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cant use same ID in one page. The ID is unique identifier, If you need use identifier more than once, use class instead.

Any way, you can use :last selector, like this:

```
$("div:last")
```

You could eaven use :last-child, like this:

```
$('#pagination:last-child')
```

Comment: It is a php include file, so the content of the file cannot change. So they both have the same id and classname.

Comment: @terrid25, in which case check out @Scoobler answer. Horrible code though that you are emitting.

Comment: :( The fathers of HTML are all squirming in their graves, wishing as one that they could reach out to you.

Answer (score 6):

If you were being correct, you should never have two ID's the same, so using `$('#selector:last')` or `$('#selector').last()` won't work, however you can cheat a little like this:

```
$("div[id=pagination]:last").......
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zzGc5/)

Comment: I had a jquery plugin that would generate a new div in the dom on every call, and this was the only way to select the newly generated div- Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, same situation as Lsdafjklsd.  The ID are dynamically generated and sometimes they overlap.

Answer (score 3):

[`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('div#pagination').last()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding the `pagination` class to both the divs (you can't have duplicate IDs) and using `$('div.pagination:last')` to grab the last one on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have multiple elements with the same ID, id must be unique.

but if you want the last occuranse of the element you can use this

```
$('selector:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

Having two elements with the same ID is not valid html.

Instead use differnet classes, e.g. pag_top, pag_bottom and select the bottom one using:

```
$(".pag_bottom")
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can get the array of divs with the same ID

```
var myDivArray = $('#pagination');
```

And then you can get the second element

```
var myDiv = myDivArray[1];
```

I hope it's helpful